# Easily parse String of Key=Value pairs to Scala case class

Tags: parsing, scala, key-value, case-class

Is there any way to easily parse a string of key value pairs into a scala case class?

For example from the following string:

```
"consumer_key=1234ABC, consumer_secret=12345ABC"
```

into

```
case class Auth(consumerKey: String, consumerSecret: String)
```

Comment: is all your strings have this structure? if so, why don't you break it explicitly? `val (key,secret) = (s.slice("consumer_key=".length,s.indexOf(",")),s.drop(s.lastIndexOf("=")))`

Comment: Nope i just posted the first two but there are more.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use regex and pattern matching:

```
scala> val R = "consumer_key=(.*), consumer_secret=(.*)".r
R: scala.util.matching.Regex = consumer_key=(.*), consumer_secret=(.*)

scala> "consumer_key=1234ABC, consumer_secret=12345ABC" match {
     |   case R(k, v) => Auth(k, v)
     | }
res0: Auth = Auth(1234ABC,12345ABC)
```

Use `JavaTokenParsers` for more flexible parsing:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

case class Auth( consumerKey: String, consumerSecret: Option[String])

class AuthParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def auth: Parser[Auth] = key ~ opt("," ~> secret) ^^ { case k ~ s => Auth(k, s)}
  def key: Parser[String] = value("consumer_key")
  def secret: Parser[String] = value("consumer_secret")
  def value(k: String): Parser[String] = k ~ "=" ~> "[^,]*".r
  def apply(s: String) = parseAll(auth, s)
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> val p = new AuthParser
p: AuthParser = AuthParser@433b9799

scala> p("consumer_key=1234ABC, consumer_secret=12345ABC").get
res0: Auth = Auth(1234ABC,Some(12345ABC))

scala> p("consumer_key=1234ABC").get
res1: Auth = Auth(1234ABC,None)
```

Comment: Thanks thats what i was looking for, Is there anyway to make one of them optional?

Comment: @AnthonyMcCormick: answer updated for optional `consumer_secret`.

Answer (score 2):

I love the scala Parsers library, but it is a little slow.  If your strings all look like that, you can just as easily do:

```
case class Auth( consumerKey:String, consumerSecret:String)
object Auth {
  def fromString(string: String): Seq[Auth] = string.split(", ").toSeq map { pair =>
    val lst = pair.split("=")
    Auth(lst(0), lst(1))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, if the pattern you're expecting is simple enough, it might be possible to pattern match it by [unapplying a string interpolator](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/StringContext$s$.html#unapplySeq(s:String):Option[Seq[String]]):

```
// case class Auth(consumerKey: String, consumerSecret: String)
"consumer_key=1234ABC, consumer_secret=12345ABC" match {
  case s"consumer_key=$key, consumer_secret=$secret" => Auth(key, secret)
}
// Auth("1234ABC", "12345ABC")
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with nnythm but that solution does not address the problem. This may work better:

```
case class Auth( consumerKey:String, consumerSecret:String)
object Auth {
  def fromString(s: String): Auth = {
    val p = s.split(", ").toSeq.map { pair => {
        val lst = pair.split("=")
        (lst(0), lst(1))
    }}.toMap
    Auth(p("consumer_key"), p("consumer_secret"))
  }
}
```

This has the added benefit of being able to have a string with any number of key value pairs and you can easily change which you choose to work with.